# On Trusty, what is CL program to create desktop configuration file?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, bash

On Precise, I used to create a desktop configuration file with my own GUI wrapper which called the `gnome-desktop-item-edit` command line program (part of the `gnome-panel` package) which had the Directory (to create the file in) and `--create-new` as parameters.

This had `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` as the first line. This seems to give problems in Trusty.

However, I noticed that Arronax (in Trusty) creates these files without that first line. Is there a command line program (to replace `gnome-desktop-item-edit`) which will do as Arronax does?

PS another question, what should I put as the Exec parameter (in the file) if it is, for example, `bash /opt/UniversalMediaServer/ums.sh`?